# JSON communication between Iphone and Wordpress?

Tags: iphone, json, wordpress

I have an Iphone developer building an app that helps the user keep track of a few basic pieces of data like  certain calendar dates ect.

I want to use Wordpress as a member only site that reflects that data recorded on iphone app. Again, this is very simple data like calendar dates. Much like an app that records running distance and reflects it on a website so the user can review it (much simpler however).

Can I use JSON to accomplish this?

I found this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/other_notes/ ... Does this help?

I basically just need the specs let the developer know where to post ect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSON to enable a standard method of communication between the Wordpress install and the iPhone app. You can use that plugin you mentioned for the Wordpress side and there are many libraries available for JSON on the iOS platform.

On the iPhone side, you will need to grab the JSON data and parse it. A good tutorial explaining how to do so is available [here](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/). It's hard to give exact details on what URL's to post to because it truly depends on how you set up your Wordpress install and more details would be needed to get into the specifics.

All in all, using JSON would be much easier to get the data to/from the iPhone onto your Wordpress site.